# JQuery validations not working empty data is inserted into table rows

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've a text field in table with id name .
I have added a validation on it.
But its not working

```
    <td>Name:</td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" id="name" class="required"/>(required)
    </td>

    $("#name").focusout(function(){
        if (!$(this).val()) {
            alert("This field is required");
            $(this).focus();
         }
    });
```

I have complete code on jsfiddle .
Please check [link](https://jsfiddle.net/cv4u0nf9/4/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make sure to put it inside document ready and it'll work just fine:

```
$(function () {
    $("#name").focusout(function () {
        if (!$(this).val()) {
            alert("This field is required");
            $(this).focus();
        }
    });
});
```

[**jsfiddle DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/samuraii/cv4u0nf9/9/)

Edit: full page requested by OP:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Dynamic Book Library</title>
    <style>
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
th, td {
    padding: 5px;
    text-align: left;
}
</style>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
var count = 1;
var rating;

function addRow() {

    var myName = document.getElementById("name");
    var auther = document.getElementById("auther");
    var publish = document.getElementById("publish");
    var ratings = document.getElementsByName("rating");
    for (var i = 0; i < ratings.length; i++) {
        if (ratings[i].checked) {
            rating = ratings[i];
        }
    }
    var table = document.getElementById("myTableData");

    var rowCount = table.rows.length;
    var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);

    row.insertCell(0).innerHTML = count;
    row.insertCell(1).innerHTML = myName.value;
    row.insertCell(2).innerHTML = auther.value;
    row.insertCell(3).innerHTML = publish.value;
    row.insertCell(4).innerHTML = rating.value;
    count = count + 1;
}

function load() {

    console.log("Page load finished");

}
$(function() {
    $("#name").focusout(function () {
        console.log('bla');
        if (!$(this).val()) {
            alert("This field is required");
            $(this).focus();
        }
    });
});
</script>

</head><body onload="load()">
    <div id="mydata">
<b>Current data in the system ...</b>

        <table id="myTableData" border="1" style="width:100%">
            <tr id="templateRow">
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Authers</th>
                <th>Published</th>
                <th>Ratings</th>
            </tr>
        </table>&nbsp;
        <br/>
    </div>
    <div id="myform">
<b>Simple form with name and age ...</b>

        <table style="width:100%">
            <tr>
                <td>Name:</td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" id="name">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Auther:</td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" id="auther">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Published:</td>
                <td>
                    <input type="date" id="publish">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Rating:</td>
                <td>
                    <input type="radio" value="1" id="rating" name="rating">1
                    <input type="radio" value="2" id="rating2" name="rating">2
                    <input type="radio" value="3" id="rating3" name="rating">3
                    <input type="radio" value="4" id="rating4" name="rating">4
                    <input type="radio" value="5" id="rating5" name="rating">5</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <br>
        <input type="button" id="add" value="Add" onclick="Javascript:addRow()">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I tried it . Its not working . For demo please refer [link](https://jsfiddle.net/cv4u0nf9/4/)

Comment: Check the demo I posted in my answer. It's based on yours (and it was linking to a wrong version which is fixed, so check it, and it works just fine)

Comment: I added `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>`  to my code its not working although its working on js filddle Can you please tell the issue ?

Comment: Do you get any error in your console? If it's a live version can you give a link?

Comment: There is no error in console. I am running it on local http server using git .Here is drop box link to index file [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/sllg6yvb3rxm021/index12txt.txt?dl=0)

Comment: You haven't added the code in your page, how do you expect it to work? Just add the code in answer at the end of your `<script` in head.

Comment: I have added the code and its in head section only please check . [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/sllg6yvb3rxm021/index12txt.txt?dl=0)

Comment: Yes now it's good and working, just change the extension from `.txt` to `.html`

Comment: If it's not working see the page source in your browser and see whether that bit of code is there. If it is and you're not getting any error in console, then I'm simply out of words.

Comment: Source it there i am trying in chrome . Is it possible for you to provide the code which is working on ur side ?

Comment: See the edit. Save it as an html file and it should work in any browser on any side. It's just a simple stand-alone page.

Comment: Dude I have done that . Yes its simple stand alone page . If you can please provide code which is working your side it will be fine

Comment: Like I said see the edit. I provided code that should work on any side (= works on my side too).